# How to connect multi remote sql server?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My localhost sql is too big.

Now I want to add another remote mysql.

Can Anyone set remote mysql in following local mysql connection?

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"

#Localhost mysql: Make it only read

$hostname_saha = "localhost";
$database_saha = "bdwebstk_1a";
$username_saha = "bdwebstk_1a";
$password_saha = "111111111111"; 

#remote mysql : Plesae make it read and write

$hostname_saha = "xx.yy.zz.zz";
$database_saha = "horjecom_aw";
$username_saha = "horjecom_aw";
$password_saha = "000000000000000000"; 

$saha = mysqli_connect($hostname_saha, $username_saha, $password_saha, $database_saha) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($saha),E_USER_ERROR); 

mysqli_set_charset( $saha, 'utf8');

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Above only I put my code. It is not edited . Can you edit it as if only localhost will read and Remote sql will read and write.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a separate connections for each of your SQL Server - preferably in separate fiels.

I would strongly recommend naming your connection names from the business pourpose that they will serve.
The other strong recommendation for you is to store your configuration files outside of the codebase https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724607/3711660

File localhost_sql.php

```php
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"

#Localhost mysql: Make it only read

$hostname_saha = "localhost";
$database_saha = "bdwebstk_1a";
$username_saha = "bdwebstk_1a";
$password_saha = "111111111111"; 

$sqlcon_localhost= mysqli_connect($hostname_saha, $username_saha, $password_saha, $database_saha) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($saha),E_USER_ERROR); 

mysqli_set_charset( $sqlcon_localhost, 'utf8');
?>
```

file remote_sql.php

```php
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"

#Localhost mysql: Make it only read


$hostname_saha = "66.96.566.53";
$database_saha = "horjecom_aw";
$username_saha = "horjecom_aw";
$password_saha = "000000000000000000"; 


$sqlcon_remote= mysqli_connect($hostname_saha, $username_saha, $password_saha, $database_saha) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($saha),E_USER_ERROR); 

mysqli_set_charset( $sqlcon_remote, 'utf8');
?>
```

Then use it in another file as below

```php
require('remote_sql.php');
$result = mysqli_query($sqlcon_remote, "SELECT DATABASE()")
```

Comment: Where I will put this code? require('remote_sql.php');
$result = mysqli_query($sqlcon_remote, "SELECT DATABASE()")    Here full code of result https://www20.zippyshare.com/v/dANfYkU7/file.html please tell me

Comment: You are already including the connection in the first line. `<?php require_once('Connections/saha.php'); ?>` - thats good, you can keep it in the already exising file, but split the declariations by variable names or create a separate Connections/saha_remove.php file and then require it in your main file :)

Comment: I put in number following way but got eror <?php require_once('Connections/saha.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc-main.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('inc.search.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('Connections/saha1.php'); ?> See my code https://www20.zippyshare.com/v/dANfYkU7/file.html

Comment: There is no error yet. I want to connect multi remote sql in localhost php script. My localhost sql size too big. Now I want localhost will only read data from sql. But remote mysql will read and write . Thus , I want add multi remote sql in my site. In above I given above my localhost mysql details and remote.

Comment: And my code solves your problem :P
The problem was that you had only one connection, but you need 2 separate ones.
Are you talking about master/slave configuration or what? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql